# Which directory structure when working with multiple databases?

Tags: laravel

Is there a recommended directory structure when working with multiple databases ? It's perhaps a subjective question, but I'd like to have some advices to avoid confusion in further developments.

Each database will have a few models and controllers (API or not).

Current (default) structure:

```
├── Console
│   └── Kernel.php
├── Exceptions
│   └── Handler.php
├── Http
│   ├── Controllers
│   │   ├── API
│   │   ├── Auth
│   │   │   ├── ConfirmPasswordController.php
│   │   │   ├── ForgotPasswordController.php
│   │   │   ├── LoginController.php
│   │   │   ├── RegisterController.php
│   │   │   ├── ResetPasswordController.php
│   │   │   └── VerificationController.php
│   │   ├── Controller.php
│   │   ├── HomeController.php
│   │   └── UserController.php
│   ├── Kernel.php
│   └── Middleware
│       ├── Authenticate.php
│       ├── CheckForMaintenanceMode.php
│       ├── EncryptCookies.php
│       ├── RedirectIfAuthenticated.php
│       ├── TrimStrings.php
│       ├── TrustProxies.php
│       └── VerifyCsrfToken.php
├── Providers
│   ├── AppServiceProvider.php
│   ├── AuthServiceProvider.php
│   ├── BroadcastServiceProvider.php
│   ├── EventServiceProvider.php
│   └── RouteServiceProvider.php
└── User.php
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your dilemma, you should check out [Nwidart's Laravel-Modules](https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v6/introduction). It's a pretty neat package that can organize your code with modules and saves you time constructing your own file structure. Go check it out!

Comment: Thanks! However, it seems to support Laravel 5, but I'm using Laravel 7.

Comment: @DevonDahon it also supports Laravel 7. Our team uses this package as well for our latest project.

Answer (score 0):

When working with multiple databases, the project directory structure does not really matter. Directory structure is purely subjective because it's you, and your team, who will navigate within your project.

Now to answer your question about working on multiple database, you should add your database connections in your `database.php` config file. You can define as many as you want and use them on `Model` level or `Controller` level and leverage Laravel DB Facade's `connection()` method which is documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database#using-multiple-database-connections).